# SQL: find the earliest occurrence of a row in a table based of values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I realize this question has been asked many times and I am have looked through many posts concerning this issue for over a day now. Unfortunately I've been unable to resolve my specific issue and would greatly appreciate any help that you all can offer.

I believe this is a variation of the "greatest-n-per-group" problem that comes up on StackOverflow several times per week.

The query is being run against a database for work tickets. The data I need is spread out across many table and I am consolidating it into a single area to work with. In this specific instance, the update table contains multiple rows for a specific work ticket. I am trying to join it to the ticket table and only grab the earliest update-date for that ticket where the user id matches the user associated with the ticket from the user table. Basically I'm using when the `user_id` is changed to determine when a ticket is being assigned to a particular user.

**UPDATE_TABLE**

```
updateNumber            | user_id       | date          | ticket_number
11                       | 4586b03       | 2011-11-30    | 923479283
12                       | 6786t03       | 2011-11-30    | 923479283
13                       | 7986003       | 2011-12-02    | 923479283
14                       | 7986003       | 2011-12-03    | 923479283
15                       | 7986003       | 2011-12-04    | 923479283
16                       | 5838397       | 2011-10-02    | 391983247
17                       | 7986004       | 2012-01-03    | 663738223
18                       | 7986003       | 2011-08-04    | 391983247
```

Query:

```
select 
    min(TA.updated_at) as UpdateVal
from Tickets T 
inner join Users U on U.id = T.assigned_user_id 
inner join UserGroup AU on U.login = AU.[User]
inner join TicketUpdate TA  on TA.task_id = T.id
where
   TA.task_id = 923479283 and TA.user_id = 7986003
```

returns:  `2011-12-02`

This approach works when I hard code the `task_id` and `user_id` for a specific row like above. However when I substitute the `T.id` for 923479283 and `U.id` for 7986003 to get this info for all the tickets the query returns nothing. I've tried many different solutions including joining the `TicketUpdate` table on itself via alias and so on.

Please HELP!

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: So, the code sample you posted is the one that _does_ run correctly, but there's another non-hardcoded sample that does _not_ run.  Is that right?  If so, can you post the bad code exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add those columns on your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select TA.task_id, TA.user_id, min(TA.updated_at) as UpdateVal
from Tickets T 
inner join Users U on U.id = T.assigned_user_id 
inner join UserGroup AU on U.login = AU.[User]
inner join TicketUpdate TA  on TA.task_id = T.id
GROUP BY TA.task_id, TA.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks i believe this worked, however i've tried this previously and it did not work as i required. Hopefully it wasn't a syntax error

Comment: This solution is correct for the situation i posted. however, i was trying to avoid posting the much larger actual query for security reasons and when i apply the changes to the larger query the solution grabs every record due mainly to how the large query is structured, i apologize but i don't think i'm allowed to post the full query, company policy and all. I will mark this correct and hopefully we can continue to discuss the issue.

Comment: the larger query contains some left outer joins to other tables could that cause the all the records to be displayed.